# Rewiring a charger power lead

Tags: power-supply, power

How do I know which wire is positive and negative when they are both white? One is coming from inside the other wire. I have taken a picture if anyone can help would be much appreciated. I'm trying to charge my computer and I'm not much of an electrician.

Comment: Measure with a voltmeter? Or failing that, see which way around you have to connect them to blow up a diode? (joking, joking, don't do that.)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do it is with a multimeter.

First of all, turn the power off to make it safe. Then strip the wires. Attach one to the red lead of a multimeter and one to the black lead. Make sure your multimeter is in the correct range. *Make sure the wires are not touching* and turn the power on.

If you get a *positive* reading, then the wire on the **RED** lead is positive and the wire on the **BLACK** lead is negative.

If you get a *negative* reading, the wire on the **RED** lead is negative and the wire on the **BLACK** lead is positive.

If you need help on how to measure voltage with a multimeter, follow this [LINK](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-multimeter/measuring-voltage).

Also, what do you mean charging up your computer? It may help to provide the picture of both the lead and the 'computer' you want to charge.